# Eclips Error com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a project in eclips...
When i open it, and select new > project > android project from existing code, it open without errors, and i can export APK easily
but when i want make a changes in name or code, i see below errors:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/1942411cff3e4e5d98508cf9d7636197.png

i did below action,but not solved yet:
click right on properties , build target, and i mark Google API and not solved...

click right on properties, java build path, and add google play service, but not solved

note: after all works, i clean project but still errors occurred.

when i click on errors, it going on below cods:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

and i remove them, and still errors occurred.

i installed google play service:
http://puu.sh/pLeCI/88272022ac.png

and still i see google play service error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found solution...
first should install google play service from SDK manager,

and then go to below directory:

<**your drive address>**\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

then copy google-play-services_lib to your desktop or anywhere,

then go to eclips and import google-play-services_lib like a project inside your previous project,(note: you should mark copy project into workspace)

then right click on your previous project, properties, android tab, in bottom of page, you see library, click on add at right of page and add google-play-services as you see there.

done.
enjoy.